# What are the small details Windows and Linux users will trip on when using OSX for the first time?

Tags: windows-7, macos, comparison

Like any other Apple product, OS X prides itself on the little details. When, earlier last week, I used my professor's Mac briefly to give a quick project presentation (mine decided to do a chkdsk at the wrong time, heh), I got the distinct feeling some were put intentionally to make the uninitiated look stupid.

What are the small usability details that Windows and Linux users *will* trip on when their friends lend them their beloved Mac for some quick web browsing?

Comment: Please do not use the "one answer per item" format. Real questions have answers, not items, so I'm going to create a CW answer with the list itself you can add items to.

Comment: See Apple's [Switch 101: On Windows, I used to...](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2514)

Comment: You've bought a Mac ergo you will have less beer money

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Window management

- The third (green) window button is used to zoom windows. Sometimes that means maximizing it to fill the screen as you might expect. More often, it will resize the window to fit its contents, or restores it to a predefined default size.
- Double-clicking the title bar minimizes the window instead of maximizing it.
- Scrolling while holding <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> zooms the whole screen, not the document.
- On Windows, <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles between open window. On OS X (and Unity), <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>⇥ tab</kbd> cycles between open applications. You can use an upwards three-finger gesture to switch between windows of the same program, although there's probably some sort of keyboard combination for that too.
- Usually, closing the last open window in an application doesn't quit it.

#### File management and Finder

- There is no way to cut items in Finder. (However, since 10.7, <kbd>⌥ option</kbd>-<kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> will move a previously copied item to the current folder.)

#### Mouse

- The traditional Mac equivalent to right-clicking is a left click while holding <kbd>⌃ control</kbd>. Most pointing devices sold by Apple now have a right button, but right-clicking is still disabled by default in System Preferences.

#### Keyboard

- In most contexts, the <kbd>⌘ command</kbd> (located where the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is on the Windows keyboard) is used instead of <kbd>⌃ control</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>)
- Similarly <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> (<kbd>Windows</kbd>) is used instead of <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.
- If an OS X program mentions the <kbd>alt</kbd> key, that's again really <kbd>⌥ option</kbd> (<kbd>Windows</kbd>)
- <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> move to beginning or end of document. Use <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd> instead to move to beginning or end of line.
- <kbd>↩ return</kbd> is commonly used for renaming items, not for opening them.
- In most applications, <kbd>⌫ delete</kbd> doesn't actually delete items — you have to use <kbd>⌘ command</kbd>-<kbd>⌫ delete</kbd> or <kbd>⌦ delete</kbd> (the smaller key next to <kbd>end</kbd>) instead.

#### Interface

- There are no mnemonic keys on the menu bar or in dialogs.

Comment: Use __↑__ the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/249302/edit) link to add items.

Comment: @mick Feel free to edit the answer and add your details

Comment: There's an *alt* labeled key. Writing you quit applications using *Alt-Q* is just plain wrong. The keys are in different order. Not a huge issue for people with eyesight. The same with "Alt-↓". You currently use *Alt* for both *Option* and *Command* (see window switching) -- Users will trip over **your key names** just as much as the actual issues.

Comment: @dan I thought the Command key is where the Alt key would be on a person using a computer normally, without looking at the keyboard -- so it would be easier for the _occasional_ user to just memorize that. At any rate, it's CW. Please fix it.

Comment: Except for the German keyboard hint, I took a shot at changing the key combinations to their Mac usage. I can't think of an intuitive way for people to "translate" their keyboard shortcuts from system to system, though, so more clarification there would be welcome.

Comment: The Apple "Mighty Mouse" ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Mighty_Mouse#About_the_mouse ) has a track-ball/button that both scrolls in 2 dimensions and middle-clicks.

Comment: @JRobert Thanks! Don't be afraid of just deleting wrong information - that's why we have revision history.

Comment: @DanielBeck Can you check if the latest edit I've made is not totally bogus?